# Куда (?) потом скажу

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, союзные-слова, нет-знака

Что ставить: а) тире, б) запятую, в) ничего?

`Завтра мы кое-куда поедем. Куда (?) потом скажу.`

В теории, возможны все варианты, если записать наоборот:

*Потом скажу куда* — придаточное, состоящее из одного союзного слова; запятая не ставится;

*Потом скажу, куда* — интонационное выделение союзного слова;

*Потом скажу — куда* — супер интонационное выделение.

Следовательно, наоборот должно так же работать.

А вы как считаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***Куда** — //  потом скажу.*

**Препозиция** изъяснительного придаточного (союзного слова куда), разная **структура** предложений. Требуется интонационное разделение, пауза обозначена **тире.**

В разговорной речи допускается **запятая**: *Куда, / потом скажу.*

**[Розенталь, пункт 1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)**

Тире ставится для **интонационного** отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует: 1) придаточная **изъяснительная:** Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять (Г.);

Comment: То есть вариант без знаков невозможен?

Comment: Думаю, что нет.

Answer (score 0):

Как это — ничего?! Только тире!

*Куда — потом скажу.*